# no data is received from an ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    url: "secret.aspx",
    data: {
        plu: $("#Text1").val(),
        gh: $("#TextBox1").val(),
        sid: $("#TextBox2").val()
    },
    dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {

            $("#result").html(data);
                               }
    });
```

I am making a call to the  `aspx` page, the call goes correctly. Data is entered in database, but values are not returned to the page

The return statements are as follows:

```
Response.Write("hello");
Response.End();
```

Comment: what `data type` are you returning? try returning `("<p>hello</p>")`

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Perhaps an error's occurring with secret.aspx. To find out, add an `error` setting to the ajax call so you get to know about any errors. You could also add an alert to display the returned data, in case it's something to do with your `result` element:

```
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#result").html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.responseText);

                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
```